# How to disable Google synchronization on Xperia XZ1 Compact?

Tags: sync, google-account

Given that I'm an Android developer and know how to use Android, I'm yet again amazed by Google's ability to disguise options and to change them with every release (in addition to the device manufacturers doing the same thing).

What I want to achieve: disable auto-sync of all data with Google (including app data, contacts, SMS, calendar, ...)

The way it **doesn't** work on my device is by following the instructions you get from googling "android how to disable Google sync". I'm not stupid ;) I do know how to google.

I have a Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact with Android 8.0 Oreo. I'm unable to disable synchronization. Here are the screenshots:

[image: Users and accounts] [image: Google account settings] [image: After clicking on "Account sync"]

Note: On the last screenshot, when scrolling down the list, I can see "Google Play Movies & TV" where it explicitly says "Sync is OFF". It **doesn't** say that for the other items.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh. I found that "auto-sync account data" (shown on the first screenshot) acts as a master switch. Turning it on and then going to the "Account sync" screen then reveals the individual on/off sliders for the different items.